# Make MKV file suitable for streaming with ffmpeg (or avconv) - how to move all metadata to beginning of file?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, matroska, libav

My question, I think, is pretty simple...

Sometimes I like to download large MKV files from a webserver of mine, and play them back while they are downloading. However, if I do this on MKV files I've transcoded, often the file will show that it is much shorter than it actually is, and after it gets to the end it will just keep playing and display an incorrect time...e.g. it will display 2:50/2:50 but keep playing, however if I try to seek backwards with the arrow keys the player will either crash or skip back to the beginning of the file.

So, how can I move all the metadata to the beginning of the file while encoding so that the player will know how long the file is without having the whole thing? [You can do this with the `mp4` format by using `-movflags faststart`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061798/post-processing-in-ffmpeg-to-move-moov-atom-in-mp4-files-qt-faststart), but how to do it for `mkv`?

I'm sorry if this is already asked and answered elsewhere, I could not think of better keywords than I used and the ones I used produced no results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Matroska foundation offers a tool, [mkclean](https://www.matroska.org/downloads/mkclean.html),  that performs a task similar to what qt-faststart does for MOV/MP4s.

Syntax:

```
mkclean in.mkv out.mkv
```

This will regenerate the cues index. To keep the original cues,

```
mkclean --keep-cues in.mkv out.mkv
```

---

FFmpeg can also do [this](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#toc-Options-7), with some guesswork, on the user's part.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -c copy -reserve_index_space 50k out.mkv
```

where the `reserve_index_space` value in bytes is the size needed for the index. `50k`bytes is the suggested size for 1 hour of media.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Before I accept--what are the benefits/drawbacks of keeping the cues versus not? Is it one of those things where if I have to ask I won't notice? :)

Comment: That would be my answer. It will render the cues to spec if regenerating them.

Comment: OK, I understand, the reason that this is happening is because the cues are all written at the end, and I need them at the front; `mkclean` will move the cues. Without `--keep-cues` it will regenerate the cues, and with it it will preserve the current cues generated by ffmpeg...but since Cues are not Chapters...not much of a difference, but probably keeping the cues takes less CPU time and disk access than regenerating them. Thanks for your help once again :D

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of [Gyan's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1190155), mkclean is that right tool to optimize MKVs for streaming. However, I noticed some quirks in how mkclean produced files, so I made a fork: https://github.com/XMB5/mkclean-pragmatic

Example usage: `mkclean test.mkv test_streaming_optimized.mkv`

Here are some excerpts from the readme:

### Background (why we need mkclean in the first place)

In order to stream mkv files, the video player needs to read the [cues element](https://www.matroska.org/technical/cues.html), a part of the file that maps video timestamps to byte offsets. These offsets allow the video player to seek to timestamps throughout the video, without guessing the byte location in the file.

Typically, the cues element is located at the end of a matroska file (see [matroska structure diagram](https://www.matroska.org/technical/diagram.html)). This is because the application that creates the mkv writes all of the video data first, and only afterwards can it know the exact byte locations of the video content.

However, having the cues element at the end of the file is not ideal: the video player must read the seek head at the start of the file, then seek the the end of the file to read the cues information, then seek back to read the video content. With HTTP streaming, this amounts to 3 separate requests, which add a few seconds of delay compared to 1 request.

`mkclean` restructures a mkv file so that the cues element is at the beginning, allowing the video to start playing sooner.

### Technical changes in fork (compared to original mkclean)

- Set doctype version to `matroska v4` by default

  - Set document read version to 2 (for compatibility, otherwise it won't work with vlc, mpv, ffmpeg, etc.)
- Disable optimizations by default (equivalent to normal mkclean `--no-optimize` flag)
- Ignore when cluster timestamps don't go in chronological order

  - Force-changing the timestamps causes mpv to warn "Invalid video timestamp: 10.085000 -> 10.060000"